# Print a string in MailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I was working on an app and I wanted to display the string `stringValue` as a variable to display when someone wants to share something from my app via email.

```
- (IBAction)openMail:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailer setSubject:@"My App"];
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tony@starkindustries.com", nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        NSString *emailBody = [@"Rating is: %@", [self.app.rating stringValue];
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
    }
```

How can I make `[self.app.rating stringValue];` be displayed as "Rating Is: **some_number**" when you openMail? Perhaps I am writing the `%@` part wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rating is: %@", [self.app.rating stringValue]];
```

will do the trick, provided that `[self.app.rating stringValue]` returns a valid `NSString` object (although `%@` specifier would work just fine for other cocoa objects like `NSNumber` etc, so if `self.app.rating` is an `NSNumber` you could format the string without even sending the `stringValue` message to it).

For more on string formatting you can have a look at Apple's [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943-CJBEAEHH)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rating is: %@", [self.app.rating stringValue];
```

[self.app.rating] needs to return a string, to use the code above.

Hope its useful and answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

you are leaving out `stringWithFormat:`

you need:

```
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rating is: %@", [self.app.rating stringValue]];
```